# Correct structure of a new MERN-project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have decided to help my friend with a website to his new company, and I figured it's a good time to try out the MERN-stack (mongodb, express, react and node.js).

But then again I'm thinking about MongoDB and if it's really optimal for this project, because there will be relational data.

The relational data there will be is customers and their objects. Let's say customers that register, and to every customer there will be one or several cars that the company uses in some way.

Is this doable in MongoDB? How would you go about structuring it in the best way? I'm thinking about a collection of users, having the objects (cars) as a field of object arrays in the user collection.

I haven't done a project in MERN before, and I'm open to any suggestion.

Also I would be very interested in having a 'mentor', I could even be open to some kind of payment having someone mentor me through this project. I hope this is not against the rules here, if it is, sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say there will be `relational data`, shouldn't you be considering SQL at first? MongoDB does support relational data through the `ref`. I can elaborate that if you can be more specific about what data are you going to be having.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking here, because maybe MERN isn't the best way of approaching this project. But it's a shame because I really wanted to try the MERN-combo right now.

The idea is something like airbnb. Customers register, and the customers will also register one or several objects to the business. So mostly it is the relation between our customers and their (1 or several) objects. Often it's just one object, but could be more, rarely more than 5-10.

Comment: What type of data are you going to be having? We can't really tell if it's a good approach just base on the information of there will be some relational data. period. We need more info man.

Comment: The relational data is just customers that register. And every customer will be offering one or several housing objects. So the relational data is customers and their housing objects.

I don't know what more to tell you, this is all.

Comment: Then MongoDB can definitely handle this.

Comment: Ok sir, thank you. But my question was how to best structure this in mongoose/mongodb.

Comment: We can't structure anything without the actual data, just like any other database schema design.

Comment: This sound absurd. You can't structure the database without the actual data? But you know what kind of data will be in there. When you build a bridge you make the blueprints before the actual material work starts.

Comment: You just said that you have some relational data, period. That's all the information we have. Who can design a schema knowing 'we have some relational ' only? We at least need to know what kind of data do we have. For example, we'll have some customers who will do this and that....  so we can know that oh actually we need to make a collection for customer information...  etc.

Comment: I got everything I need. Don't worry about it. I just need some help in figuring out bow I'm about to the relationality, in a pure technical sense! Interested in helping me?

Comment: Ok. I am going to post the potential suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle relational data in MongoDB, you will have to take advantage of the `DBrefs` feature.

I am taking thos example straight from one of my projects in production.

The schema is heavily truncated but still tells the story of the `DBrefs` feature.

It consists of two schemas: activity & user

> The activity schema is here:

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Global Constant
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ActivitySchema = new Schema({
    activity: {
        type: String,

    },

    description: {
        type: String,

    },
    intensity: {
        type: String,
    },
    hostId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'

    },

}, {
    collection: 'Activity'
});

mongoose.model('activity', ActivitySchema);
```

> The user schema is here:

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Global Constant
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,

    },
    nickName: {
        type: String

    },
    email: {
        type: String,

    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    profImage: {
        type: String,

    },
    interests: {
        type: Array,

    },

}, {
    collection: 'User'
});

mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

As you can see, there is a field called `hostId` at the end of the activity schema with a type of `Schema.Types.ObjectId` and a `ref:` field which points to the user schema.

What it does essentially is to virtually link the two documents together by storing the `ObjectId` of the user in the activity collection (called a table in SQL).

The two documents are only actually linked together when and only when a query function, for example,`.findOne()` is called along with  the `.populate()` aggregation operator.

> Example:

```js
//Syntax: database.collection.queryFunction

//Normal Query:

db.activity.findOne({activity:'stack overflow event`})

.then(activityData=>{

console.log(activityData);

//You will get something like this:

[
    {
        activity: 'stack overflow event',
        description: 'It's all about SO',
        intensity: 'Very chill',
        hostId: ObjectId(5ea1e3c89dcab6c27d1eb891),
    }
]



})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))


//When you use .populate()

db.activity.findOne({activity:'stack overflow event`})
.populate('user')
.then(activityData=>{

console.log(activityData);

//You will get something like this:

[
    {
        activity: 'stack overflow event',
        description: 'It's all about SO',
        intensity: 'Very chill',
    //The hostId field will get populate with the user object
        hostId: {
            name: 'SO Test User',
            nickName: 'soTest',
            email: 'xxx@xxx.com',
            ....it continues

        }
    }
]


})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```